# How do I set Firebase Firestore Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to figure out why my rules for reading data from the strokedata collection won't work. The document id is the uid of the user that created the document and the coachuid is the uid of another user. I can't seem to make the read permissions work, so I am wondering what I am missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

       function isSignedIn() {
              return request.auth != null;
            }

        match /strokedata/{document} {

          allow write: if isSignedIn() && document == request.auth.uid;
          allow read: if document == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid == resource.data.coachuid; 

           }  

         match /users/{document} {

          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
          allow write: if document == request.auth.uid; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the client request code:

```
self.db.collection("strokedata").whereField("sessionid", isEqualTo:  self.currentsession as Any).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
if let err = err {


 print("Error getting documents: \(err)")

 } else {

 for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
 print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

            if let watts = document["watts"], let split =   document["currentsplit"], let time = document["time"], let strokerate = document["strokerate"], let distance = document["distance"]  {

            self.lblCurrentWatts.text = "\(watts)"

            let splitS = split as! Double
            let timestring = splitS.asString(style: .positional)

            let timeS = time as! Double
            let splitstring = timeS.asString(style: .positional)

            self.split500.text = "\(timestring)"
            self.timeElapsedData.text = "\(splitstring)"
            self.strokeRateData.text = "\(strokerate)"

            self.lblDistance.text = "\(distance)m"

            if document["heartrate"] == nil {
            self.heartRateData.text = "\(0)"
                                           } else {
            if let heartrate = document["heartrate"] {
            self.heartRateData.text = "\(heartrate)"

                        }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to also show the client request that isn't working the way you expect with these rules.  We need to see that the code matches the rules.

Comment: OK, have done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't match your rules.  Your query is only apply a single filter on the field `sessionid`, but your rules a requiring the that the user can only read documents with an ID that matches their UID or document whose `coachuid` matches their UID.  Since your query neither identifies the document to read nor filters with an appropriate value of `coachuid`, it fails every time.

If you were expecting that this rule act as a filter for allowing only certain documents to be read by a user, that won't work because [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) (be sure to read the docs at that link).

Comment: OK, thanks Doug. It is becoming clearer now. I have changed the query for the coachuid where clause and the rules to just apply the request.auth.id to that field, but still had no success. I will keep trying until I get something that works. I think I am further along now.

Comment: Doug, I got it to work, but curiously it only worked on the document field uid (which I put the uid of the other person who is allowed to read the file. I notice in the rules panel that uid turns green when I enter resource.data.uid, however, coachuid does not turn green when I enter resource.data.coachuid and so the uid works but the coachuid does not work even when the query is changed to where clause on the coachuid value.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you mean.  Please ask another question and include rules and screenshots that illustrate what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Doug, I have just posted another question with everything documented. Just curious why one way works and the other way does not. Thanks in advance.